# htaccess rewrite match numbers with names

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have to redirect a broken link so I went to many redirect generation tools to do it but none of them seem to work.

[found out special chars do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086677/301-htaccess-redirect-with-special-characters)

code below:

```
Redirect 301 /pages/view-colours/view.php?collection=cottage-garden&colour=fallen-fruit http://www.mynewdomain.com/en-GB/collections/cottage-garden/m/product/view/5/preserve-elements
```

Now I read the answer above but the problem is that the old link had the name of the product and the new system uses the id instead (view/5)

This has to be done in .htaccess, Is there anyway I can create something like an array to match numbers with names and then create a general rule that will redirect every product? or do I have to create a rewrite rule for every single product? (there are many products so I really don't want to be doing this)

Comment: I don't think there is an array system in htaccess to do what you want. You may try to automatically generate this htaccess with the programming language you use and where you have access to your database

Comment: Thanks okio, I kinda suspected that but worth a try :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /pages\/view-colours\/view\.php\?collection=cottage-garden&colour=fallen-fruit\ HTTP 
RewriteRule ^ http://www..mynewdomain.com/en-GB/collections/cottage-garden/m/product/view/5/preserve-elements [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked just fine for this product, do I have to do 1 rewrite rule per product since I have to match them with numbers?

Comment: No problem, yeah you will